# bijective differentiable function with nondifferentiable inverse?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, diffeomorphism

I recently learnt the term `diffeomorphism` which is defined as a bijective differentiable function where the inverse is differentiable. That seems to imply the existence of an bijective differentiable function with non differentiable inverse, and I am struggling to find an example where that is the case.

Comment: $y=x^3$ is one example. In general, $\frac{df^{-1}(m)}{dm}=1/f'(f^{-1}(m))$ so at point $x$ where $f'=0,(f^{-1})'$ will not be defined at $f(x)$.

Comment: ah because the cuberoot is not differentiable at 0?

Comment: yes that is right